# compare 2 columns from 2 different csv files

Tags: shell, awk

My intention is to compare a particular column of 2 different csv files & get the data from second file what is not there in first file. For example.

First File

```
"siddhartha",1
"mukherjee",2
```

Second file

```
"siddhartha",1
"mukherjee",2
"unique",3
```

Expected output

```
"unique",3
```

The below command is working properly when the text size of the first column is limited, so in the above example its working.

```
awk -F',' 'FNR==NR{a[$1];next};!($1 in a);' file1.csv file2.csv > file3.csv
```

but is the text size of the 1st column is quite large (for example 10000 char), its not working. its cutting the text at a certain point.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Is sorting the files an option? If so, use `comm` for this

Comment: sorting is a problem, the everything in between "" (data of 1 cell) has to be sorted. I tried this, not working, its sorting line by line.

Comment: please do not cross post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718016/compare-2-columns-from-2-different-csv-files

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to indicate that first column and second column are independent, so sorting by line may be ok.  You seem to be looking for a unique line. If they are already alphabetically sorted by first column, try `diff file1.csv file2.csv` and see if that gets you closer to your goal (I suppose differing whitespace could foul it up)

Comment: What version of awk are you using and do you know around when it is failing? I tested using GNU awk 3.1.7 and it was handling var's all the way past 100,000 chars.

Comment: awk --version
awk version 20070501

getting this version in mac osx

Answer (score 1):

Based on your simple sample above this should work. It will fail if it is possible that any data from the first column could end up in any other column or there are any spaces in the data.

Using bash and GNU grep.

```
grep -v -Ff <(cut -d',' -f 1 file1.csv) file2.csv > file3.csv
```

**Explanation**

- `-v` inverted matching
- `-Ff` use a file for a source of patterns
- `<(cut -d',' -f 1 file1.csv)` get the first column of data and use it as our "file".

Comment: Indeed based on the sample it works, even the awk above works al well. But it doesn't work for a complicated  CSVs. I'll try to attach them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using not awk but [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/tree/v4.5.0):

```
$ mlr --nidx join -u -j 1 --np --ur -f file1.csv file2.csv
"unique",3
```

Description:

- `--nidx` since the columns are positionally indexed (i.e. there are no header lines)
- `-u` join option to not require sorted inputs
- `-j 1` to join on column 1 for both left and right files
- `--np --ur` to not emit paired lines but do emit unpaired lines on the right-hand file